# Django clean: Determine the new line character in TemporaryFileUploadHandler chunk

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-file-upload

During the upload of a file I need to split its contents in lines, count the characters of each line and raise and error if they exceed a certain length.

```
class TheModel(models.Model):
    upload_file = models.FileField(
        upload_to='the/path'
    )


class TheForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean_upload_file(self):
        the_file = self.cleaned_data.get('upload_file')
        if the_file:
            for chunk in upload_file.chunks():  # the file is huge
                import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
```

The `the_file` is opened in `rb+` mode. The current part of its contents is:

```
>>>print(chunk)
b' counterproductive\nbishop\nsa raindrop\nsangu'
>>>print(the_file.mode)
'rb+'
```

It is obvious that the end of the byte is the beginning of a new line that will continue in the next iteration.

```
>>>print(chunk.splitlines())
[b' counterproductive', b'bishop', b'sa raindrop', b'sangu']
```

The above method will not help in telling whether the last entry is an entire line or not. On the other hand, `\n` is not guaranteed to be a line separator for every uploaded file in binary mode.

If the new line character varies (may be `\n` or `\r\n` for example), how can I distinguish whether the last entry of the list represents the end of a line or just the first part of a new one?

Comment: Have you considered looking at the next chunk for the next newline character?

Comment: @Eqomatic How can I determine which is the new line character? It may be `\n`, `\r\n` or some more options. Isn't it so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`UploadedFile.multiple_chunks()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/files/uploads/#django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile.multiple_chunks) gives the opportunity to drop the first and the last entry of the list provided by `splitlines()` if the data are larger than 2,5 Megabytes which is the default.

```
validation_list = (
    chunk.splitlines()[1:len(chunk.splitlines())-1] 
    if the_file.multiple_chunks()
    else chunk.splitlines()
)
```

This way, only a few of the hundreds of thousand lines will be skipped in this preliminary check, keeping the loss ratio very low. This is better than risking a false alarm by validating a line that through the effort of reconstructing it from possible chunks scattered between iterations, may not be identical to the original.